# How to create a list view from a database table?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, recursion

I'm querying a category table `id, parent_id, name` to generate list view of all the categories and sub-categories. What I have so far is:

- HP

  - Laptops
  - PC
- Sports

  - Sunglasses
- Food
- House

The function that I use to generate the output is:

```
public function get_category($parent_id = NULL)
{ 
    $query = $this->db->get_where('category', array('parent_id' => $parent_id))->result();
    $result = '';

    foreach ($query as $row)
    {
        $i = 0;

        if ($i == 0) 
        {
            $result .= '<ul>';  
        }

        $result .= '<li><a href="'.base_url().'category/edit/'.$row->id.'">' . $row->name;
        $result .= $this->get_category($row->id);
        $result .= '</li>';

        $i++;

        if ($i > 0) 
        {
            $result .= '</ul>';
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
HP
HP > Laptops
HP > PC
Sports
Sports > Sunglasses
Food
House
```

Comment: subcategories are stored in the same table or different?

Comment: The subcategories are in the same table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
public function get_category($parent_id = NULL,$level, $prev = "")
{ 
    $query = $this->db->get_where('category', array('parent_id' => $parent_id))->result();
    $result = '';

    foreach ($query as $row)
    {
       $temp = $prev;
       if($level == 0){
        $temp .= '<a href="'.base_url().'category/edit/'.$row->id.'">' . $row->name.'</a>';
       }else{
        $temp .= ' &gt; <a href="'.base_url().'category/edit/'.$row->id.'">' . $row->name.'</a>';
       }
        $result .= $temp;
        $result .= "<br />";
        $result .= $this->get_category($row->id, $level + 1, $temp);

    }

    return $result;
}
```

First run of this function should be

```
get_category(NULL, 0, "");
```

Here

- `NULL` is parent id (you can use a loop to dynamicaly pass id)
- `level` should be `0`
- `prev` should be empty

Answer (score 0):

I've created a demo according to your needs and it worked for me. I'm sharing the code below, I've done explaining in the comments wherever necessary. See if it helps you. 
**Controller**

```
public function get_category($parent_id = NULL){ 

    // get the {category}, {sub_category} from the table, if {sub_category} stored in different table use {JOIN}
    $data['category'] = $this->db->get_where('category', array('parent_id' => $parent_id))->result();  

    $this->load->view('your-view', $data); 
}
```

**View**

```
<?php 

if(!empty($category)){ // check if {$category} has value; if not, do nothing

    $catArr = array();  // initialize array to store category id

?>

<ul>  <!-- Start ul -->

<?php 

    foreach($category as $cat){ //loop through all the {category} array

        // check if the {cat_id} already exists in array; if not, do so where {cat_id} is category id(change your value here)
        if( ! in_array( $cat->cat_id, $catArr ) ){ 

            $catArr[] = $cat->event_id;

        ?>  

        <li><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></li>  <!-- show {cat_name} in list -- your category name here -->

        <?php

        }

        ?>

    <!-- Show {cat_name} and {subcat_name} both -- (your values here). Give links or whatever here(your styling)-->
    <li><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?> &gt; <?php echo $cat->subcat_name; ?></li>

    <?php

    } 

    ?>

</ul>

<?php 

} 

?>
```

> **OUTPUT**
>
> ```
> Honda
> Honda > Car
> Honda > Bike
> Philips 
> Philips > Electricals
> Philips > Electronics
> ```

Comment: My category table fields are `id, parent_id, name`. I'm getting error with `$cat->subcat_name`. I don't have that field.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in the comment you have to change the field name according to your table